# How to pass a method as a Delegate the short way?

Tags: c#

I have a my method `X` that invokes method `Y` that I want to be passed as a parameter.
The challenge is the `Y` can virtually be any method, but in my specific case it can be an `Action`, `Func<bool>` or `Func<int?>`. Here's receiving end:

```cs
void X(Delegate y) {
    if (y is Action action) { /* ... */ }
    else if (y is Func<bool> boolFunction) { /* ... */ }
    else if (y if Func<int?> intFunction) { /* ... */ }
    else throw new NotImplementedException();
  // do the other stuff depending on `y`
}
```

Using this as:

```cs
X(Y);
```

doesn't compile and shows:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Delegate'

However, invoking like this:

```cs
X(new Action(() => Y()));
```

works! My problem with this is it looks ugly, involves "useless" boilerplate code, using lambdas to just call method, instead passing method as delegate.

Of course it is solvable by creating 3 different method signatures, accepting `Action`, `Func<bool>` and `Func<int?>` as delegate argument, but again - BOILERPLATE code, repeating code - all the things I want to avoid here.

So what is the succinct an elegant way to solve this in C#?

EDIT: To clarify the question - this is a "code golf" type of a question. There are many, many ways to do what I intend to do, they all work, and I have even a great choice in fast and slow solutions, because in my specific case the performance is not important (it handles user click, and all `Reflection` calls in the world are way faster than users's mice). I asked the question to improve my advanced C# skills guessing there are some syntax flavors more elegant and matched to the particular challenge. That's the way I learned C# from scratch. You can use callbacks if you don't know "async / await" syntax, you can use loops if you don't know LINQ. You can pass boxed objects if you don't know how to use generics. If there is a specialized language feature to express the idea in a better way - I want to learn it.

Comment: Do you not need to do anything with the return values?

Comment: Can you show us a complete, working example of your code, even if it is ugly, so that we have something that we can work with?

Comment: "X(new Action(() => Y()));" is creating an anonymous method, that is involving resource and time overhead. In the specific case you can use "X((Action)Y)", that will implicitly work because Action is derived from Delegate.

Comment: How short do you want? Is `X((Action)Y)` short enough?

Comment: @Rubidium37 Only if `Y` can be converted to `Action`, which wont always be the case according to the question.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay `X((Action)Y)`,  `X((Func<bool>)Y)`, etc... When invoking `X(Delegate y)` by passing a "Y" method, the type of the method is known and the proper cast is writable with little effort.

Comment: @Rubidium37 Yes, agreed.

Comment: I'm not clear how much code is actually duplicated when you have 3 separate methods - you can - having some shared helpers and possibly having a small stub method that creates an `Action` from `Func<bool>`, for example should get you most of the way there without duplication. Difficult to know without seeing more realistic code - at the moment, your example method has *no* shared code, and is really 3 separate methods in disguise.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay : yes, if `bool` is returned, I want to return it as my `X` result, if nothing is returned, I assume `true`, if `int?` is returned, i want to return true if not null. Real `Y` is a backend delegate that does something with my data context, but can as well skip any actions because it got not enough data, data is not changed, or it is changed, but I don't really care about the fact the data was changed. Using the function directly is simple: `Y()` and that's it, or `if (Y()) Z()` if needed.

Comment: @Sweeper : THAT IS NICE. It actually works and it's pretty short. Definitely better than creating lambdas.

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because you are passing in `Y`, which could refer to any overload with the name `Y`. This could be returning an `int`, passing in a `string` etc. The compiler doesn't know which overload to use, so it's giving you that error. You just need to tell it what delegate type it is:

1. `X(new Action<int>(Y));`
2. `X((Action<int>)Y);`
3. This will require a slight modification to your code, but `X<Action<int>>(Y)`
   (Change your definition of `X` to

```cs
private void X<TDelegate>(TDelegate del) where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    if (del is Action action) { /* ... */ }
    else if (del is Func<bool> boolFunction) { /* ... */ }
    else if (del is Func<int?> intFunction) { /* ... */ }
    else throw new NotImplementedException();
    // do the other stuff depending on `y`
}
```

ReSharper actually suggested to convert it to a `switch`:

```cs
private void X<TDelegate>(TDelegate del) where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    switch (del)
    {
        case Action action: /* ... */
            break;
        case Func<bool> boolFunction: /* ... */
            break;
        case Func<int?> intFunction: /* ... */
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    // do the other stuff depending on `y`
}
```

P.S. I believe generic is the most efficient, and `X(new Action(()=> Y()))` is needlessly verbose and makes the compiler introduce extra functions. If you have to use it, simplify it to `X(new Action(Y))`

Comment: Wow, that looked very promising, I changed my signature like above, but I just get another compiler error: "Type arguments for method X cannot be infered from the usage". Then when I provide the type as "Func<bool>" (and my method `Y` CAN be passed as Func<bool>) - I get "Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<bool>`. BTW, there should be `Delegate`, not `delegate` at the first line of the example.

Comment: Note that Delegate as a generic constraint requires at least C# 7.3 [Delegate constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#delegate-constraints)

Comment: @Harry I've fixed the constraint issue. I'm not sure what your error is, it works fine for me:

```public void Test()
{
 X<Func<bool>>(Y);
}
private bool Y()
{
 return false;
}
 
private void X<TDelegate>(TDelegate del) where TDelegate : Delegate {}
```

Comment: @Harry what issues are you having?

Comment: @RowanRadosav-McRae At the moment: none. Corrected version works, however, I read more about huge costs of dynamic invoke and decided to put a constraint on my delegates to always return a value. Then I can use generic types instead of the Delegate type, which is much faster and easier to debug. BTW, accepting `Func<T>` instead of `Delegate` makes type inference in the compiler just work, so `X(Y)` is a valid invocation.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with one overload method :

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InvokeMethod(MethodVoid);
        InvokeMethod(MethodBool);
        InvokeMethod(MethodInt);
    }

    public static void InvokeMethod(Action x)
    {
        x.Invoke();
    }

    public static void InvokeMethod<T>(Func<T> x)
    {
        InvokeMethod(() => x());
    }

    public static void MethodVoid()
    {

    }

    public static bool MethodBool()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static int? MethodInt()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also nice, one overload is acceptable, especially when many `T` will be used in code. Another advantage is the type is set at compile time, not at runtime. If I forced my argument to be Func<T> even the overload would not be needed.